# ExcelVB Programming Application

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, microsoft-excel-365

I am looking to create an application to generate graphs for machine run time logs.
I am looking to paste a values from multiple cells say "B5","B6","E5","E6","J5", and "J6" into respective cells on a different sheet.

The hard part is I only want the data to transfer if the date of input matches the date title of the column on the second sheet.

What kind of command should I be using to move/copy the data while placing it in the correct date location. Preferably with a clickable button.

Currently I have found videos on youtube as I am no VB programmer and this is what i have made in a button

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim FirstShiftStart As Integer, FirstShiftEnd As Integer, SecondShiftStart As Integer, SecondShiftEnd As Integer, Today As Date

Worksheets("App").Select
FirstShiftStart = Range("D5")
FirstShiftEnd = Range("G5")
SecondShiftStart = Range("D6")
SecondShiftEnd = Range("G6")
Worksheets("BACKEND").Select
If Worksheets("backend").Range("B3").Equals("Today") <> "" Then
    If Worksheets("BACKEND").Range("B4").Offset(1, 0) <> "" Then
    Worksheets("BACKEND").Range("B4").End(x1Right).Select
    End If
Else
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.Value = FirstShiftStart
ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Select
ActiveCell.Value = SecondShiftStart
Worksheets("App").Select

End Sub
```

App would be the sheet the user would see, with fillable values at D5 D6 G5 and G6 (J5 and J6) to be added later as strings for transfering comments if needed.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have is not going to do anything and it is and it is very difficult to see what you are trying to achieve, I have re-written some working code below with some annotation.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim FirstShiftStart As Long, FirstShiftEnd As Long, SecondShiftStart As Long, SecondShiftEnd As Long

Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = Sheets("App") ' declares ws1 as sheet App
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = Sheets("BACKEND") ' declares ws2 as sheet BACKEND

'Assigns the values from the ranges to the variables, NB they have to be round numbers as you have declared them Integers or Long (which wind up the same in VBA apparently)
FirstShiftStart = ws1.Range("D5")
FirstShiftEnd = ws1.Range("G5")
SecondShiftStart = ws1.Range("D6")
SecondShiftEnd = ws1.Range("G6")
Debug.Print SecondShiftStart

If ws2.Range("B3") = Date Then ' Date returns todays date in VBA, this tests if B3 = todays Date
    If ws2.Range("B4").Offset(1, 0) <> vbNullString Then ' Tests if BACKEND("B5") is empty (offsets 1 row down from b4)
    'what do you want to happen here?
    ws2.Range("B6") = SecondShiftStart ' Eg
    End If
End If
'the above nested if statement will copy the value from App("D6") to BACKGROUND("B6") if BACKGROUND("B3") = Todays date and if BACKGROUND("B4") is not  = ""
'you can achieve the same in one line using:

If ws2.Range("B3") = Date And ws2.Range("B4").Offset(1, 0) <> vbNullString Then ws2.Range("B7") = FirstShiftStart

End Sub
```

Try and avoid selecting and activating cells etc, it is slow and unnecessary. Try and adapt the code above to what you want to achieve then post back.

Note the debug.print line, if you go to your VBA window and make the immediate window visible from the View dropdown it should print the value out there. This is a useful debugging tool (you can either run to the line one line below the debug.print by placing the cursor at the line using CTRL-F8, run all the code using the green run button, or link it to the commandbutton1.

also use compileVBAproject from the Debug dropdown menu prior to running the code, this would have picked up that you have used "xlright" instead of "xltoright" for example, prior to running the code and saves time.
You should also use Option Explicit at the top of the page to which helps make sure you declare all your variables correctly.

Good luck.

Comment: Awesome! I will definitely try this tonight as I am doing this on my time not at work, Thanks for the response!